# Cómo usar la función Zip en diccionarios?

Tags: python-3.x

tengo que imprimir con las lineas separadas estos tres diccionarios y la verdad, me estoy liando, lo primero que pienso es en convertir en listas los tres diccionarios para después crear unas listas de cada clave con sus correspondientes valores, pero no creo que ese sea el camino

Si alguien me puede aportar un camino más corto y sencillo se lo agradecería.
Saludos y gracias de antemano

```
   lloyd = {
    "name":"Lloyd",
    "homework":[90.0,97.0,75.0,92.0],
    "quizzes":[88.0,40.0,94.0],
    "tests":[75.0,90.0]
    }
    alice = {
    "name":"Alice",
    "homework":[100.0,92.0,98.0,100.0],
    "quizzes":[82.0,83.0,91.0],
    "tests":[89.0,97.0]
    }
    tyler = {
    "name":"Tyler",
    "homework":[0.0,87.0,75.0,22.0],
    "quizzes":[0.0,75.0,78.0],
    "tests:[100.0,100.0]
     }
```

Tengo que conseguir con una función una estructura similar a ésta (los números obviamente no son los mismos):

```
name=['lloyd','Alice','Tyler']
homework=[34,345,345]
quizzes=[23,45,676,34]
tests=[34,67,45,33]
```

Yo me he centrado en como convertir los diccionarios en listas y lo que he puesto estoy seguro que no es el camino apropiado

```
lista_estu=[lloyd,alice,tyler]
```

Este primero fue un intento que salió mal

```
lista_lloyd_k=list(lloyd.keys())
lista_lloyd_v=list(lloyd.values())
lista_alice_k=list(alice.keys())
lista_alice_v=list(alice.values())
lista_tyler_k=list(tyler.keys())
lista_tyler_v=list(tyler.values())
```

Y estos últimos pues tampoco lo veo.Creo que es con zip pero cuando lo he usado el resultado ha sido desastroso
Si me echáis una mano os lo agradeceré y disculpad los errores de bulto que pueda cometer, estoy aprendiendo.
Saludos

Comment: Prueba el camino que conoces ahora mismo, corre tu código y trae los errores o problemas que encuentres. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: También muestra el resultado esperado. No se entiende muy bien como lo quieres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para juntar varios diccionarios se crea primero un diccionario vacío, que construiremos el resultado deseado.

Luego recorremos los diccionarios extrayendo llave y valor. Si la llave no existe en el diccionario de salida, creamos una entrada con la llave y como valor, una lista vacia.

Ahora que está garantizado que la llave existe en el diccionario de salida, agregamos el valor leido a la lista de valores.

Al terminar el proceso, hemos construido un diccionario que reune a todos los demás:

**Código**

```
def junta_dic(*diccionarios):
    resultado = {}
    for dic in diccionarios:
        for llave, valor in dic.items():
            if llave not in resultado:
                resultado[llave] = []
            if type(valor) is str:
                resultado[llave].append(valor)
            else:
                resultado[llave].extend(valor)
    return resultado

for llave, valor in junta_dic(lloyd, alice, tyler).items():
    print(f"'{llave}'= {valor}")
```

produce:

```
'name'= ['Lloyd', 'Alice', 'Tyler']
'homework'= [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0, 100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0, 0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0]
'quizzes'= [88.0, 40.0, 94.0, 82.0, 83.0, 91.0, 0.0, 75.0, 78.0]
'tests'= [75.0, 90.0, 89.0, 97.0, 100.0, 100.0]
```

**Análisis**

En la definición de la función usamos la forma `*diccionarios` para consolidar en una lista cualquier número de diccionarios que nos pasen:

```
def junta_dic(*diccionarios):
```

por lo que son validas llamadas como

```
r1 = junta_dic(dicc1, dicc2)
r2 = junta_dic(dicc1, otro_dicc, mas_dicc, ultimo)
```

Para agregar elementos al resultado usamos `append` o `extend` según sea el caso. Usamos `append` para agregar los strings al resultado, ya que `extend` los considera como una lista de caracteres separados.